# What determines the parent in ggplot "normalized parent coordinates"?

Tags: r, ggplot2, coordinates, parent

In this example, the position of the statistics text is given in "normalized parent coordinates" (NPC):

```
ggplot2::ggplot(data.frame(x = c(2, 3, 4), y = c(2, 2.5, 4)), 
    aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    ggplot2::coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 5), ylim = c(1, 5)) +
    ggpubr::stat_cor(label.x.npc = 0, label.y.npc = 1)
```

However, the label does not start at `(1, 5)` as one might think (if the cartesian coordinate system where the parent), but at `(2, 4)`, the limits of the data. Why is that so? What determines the parent in NPC?

[image]

Comment: For vanilla ggplot2, the parent is the panel, so it is the position scale limits + expansion. Internally, ggplot2 uses `scales::rescale(your_data, to = c(0, 1), from = panel_limits)` (pseudocode) to convert the data to npcs. I don't know about the ggpubr function though.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

This is a summary of Christophe Nicault's knowledge provided in a fantastic manner here https://www.christophenicault.com/post/npc_ggplot2/.

- In ggplot2 the coordinate system (cartesian) is used to place the
  elements in the plot. This is sufficient if you work with one plot.
- In case of multiple plots or elements to be placed a **relative**
  scale to a parent element is used. For this task we use a different
  coordinate system called “Normalized Parent Coordinates” or NPC.

Defintion:
NPC = Normalized Parent coordinates ->  parent coordinates normalized from 0 to 1.

- The origin is (0, 0) e.g. bottom left corner
- Top right corner is at the coordinate (1, 1)
- The maximum size is 1 of both axis

For example:
The origin of npc viewport is (0,0) with a width and height of 1 unit (e.g. (0.5, 0.5) is the centre of the viewport).

**First answer**
With this code `stat_cor(method = "pearson", label.x = 1, label.y = 5)` you can position the parameters whereever you want in your cartesian

```
library(ggpubr)
ggplot2::ggplot(data.frame(x = c(2, 3, 4), y = c(2, 2.5, 4)), 
                aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  ggplot2::coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 5), ylim = c(1, 5)) +
  stat_cor(method = "pearson", label.x = 1, label.y = 5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - that was not the question, unfortunately :)

Comment: I tried to give an explanation. Please see my edit. I am not sure.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have answered yet another question, but not mine ;) the question is not "what are NPCs and how are they used", but "what is the parent in NPCs"?

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I thought the parent in NPC is the origin (0, 0) e.g. bottom left corner. Anyway it is a good question!

Comment: Yes, it's the origin, but of *what*? ;) Obviously not the cartesian coordinate system, see my quesion.

Comment: Ok. This is beyond my scope. I for myself feel ok to accept that the origin of npc viewport is (0,0) . And I know that it is not that easy. But not knowing which level your knwoledge is, I recommend this <https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/useR2015-grid/grid-slides.html> for you. Would be happy to get a note whenever you find the origin of what so ever... ;).